# Why server does not down when capistrano restart puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

My question is knowledge question, it is not for fixing a bug or a task, I see when we use capistrano to deploy application to server, capistrano do many action like, pre complile, migrate, restart puma... I confuse while capistrano is working, my website is still live because I see capistrano need restart puma. I think capistrano make a copy version of web and wait until deployment is finish and switch to new state.

This is a question interview I am asked. So please explain for me.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official source](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/)

```
├── current -> /var/www/my_app_name/releases/20150120114500/
├── releases
│   ├── 20150080072500
│   ├── 20150090083000
│   ├── 20150100093500
│   ├── 20150110104000
│   └── 20150120114500
├── repo
│   └── <VCS related data>
├── revisions.log
└── shared
    └── <linked_files and linked_dirs>
```

> current is a symlink pointing to the latest release. This symlink is
> updated at the end of a successful deployment. If the deployment fails
> in any step the current symlink still points to the old release.
>
> releases holds all deployments in a timestamped folder. These folders
> are the target of the current symlink.

So there you have the reason for your site not going down during deployment, which would completely defeat the purpose of using such a nice tool as Capistrano.